# Client denied by server configuration

Tags: apache-http-server, gitolite

I have set up an Apache server for the purpose of hosting gitolite. I've followed [this guide](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/ssh-and-http.html), but when accessing the server I get a 403, and the apache error log contains this line:

> [error] [client 192.168.0.97] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/bin/gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh

As far as my understanding goes, this means the apache user can't open the wrapper script? Most pages detailing the "client denied by server configuration" message write about directories needing an `Allow from all`, but since the `/var/www/bin/` directory isn't even supposed to be browsed, that shouldn't be the issue, I'd think?

The suexec part of the vhost config looks like this:

```
    SuexecUserGroup git git
    ScriptAlias /git/ /var/www/bin/gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh/
    ScriptAlias /gitmob/ /var/www/bin/gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh/
```

I'm running gitolite 3.5.2 and apache 2.2.25 on a gentoo 3.10.7 server. Apache is running under the user `apache`, and gitolite under `git`. These are the access rights for the suexec directories:

```
# ls -la /var/www/bin/ /var/www/git/
/var/www/bin/:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 git    git  4096 Dec  9 21:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 apache root 4096 Dec  9 21:25 ..
-rwx------ 1 git    git   249 Dec  9 21:27 gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh

/var/www/git/:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Dec  9 21:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 apache root   4096 Dec  9 21:25 ..
```

What more should I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "fixed" it, though it feels like a hack to me. I added this

```
    <Directory /var/www/bin>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

... to the vhost config. I would have guessed that it should not really be necessary, since it is not an actual client request that opens this directory?

I also had to remap my git user and group, since suexec was compiled to force uid/gid > 1000, but the gentoo installer made them system accounts, which yielded a low id.